# Prism Migration from version 6.3 to 8.1

Tags: prism, prism-6

I have a WPF Prism application in 6.3 need to upgrade it to Prism 8.1, there are lots of changes on levels of bootstrapper class, Prism Logger being depreciated in 8.1, I'm using PrismApplication class from Prism.WPF in place of bootstrapper, Am I going in right direction?

How do I implement EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.NetCore for logging in Prism 8.1, I don't want to use any 3rd party loggers like serilog, log4net or logn as there is a dependency wrt other application?

Can anyone suggest any sample code or link for Migration of Prism from 6.3 to Prism 7.0 or above.

Thanks!

I tried implementing PrismApplication class instead of Bootstrapper as it is depreciated.

Wrt to logging in prism I tried Registering Serilog in Prism Container but I want to use EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.NetCore due to some dependency.